# awk not working in for loop

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have an awk command that works fine:

```
awk '$1==1{print $1,$2,$4}' file > out1
```

If I put the same awk command in a for loop however, I only get emtpy output files:

```
for i in {1..22}
do
awk '$1==$i{print $1,$2,$4}' file > out$i
done
```

This gives 22 empty output files.
What is wrong with the for loop?

Comment: You got your answer but just to make sure it's clear: `i` is a shell variable, not an awk variable. awk is not shell. Your shell variables are not visible inside an awk script any more than they would be inside a C program, hence the need to pass the VALUE of a shell variable into awk by means of an awk variable (or other less desirable methods, see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24).

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in {1..22}
do
awk -v num="$i" '$1==num{print $1,$2,$4}' file > out$i
done
```

Answer (score 1):

try this line:

```
awk -vvar="$i" '$1==var{print $1,$2,$4}' file >out$i
```

actually you don't need that for loop, if your $1 is always an integer, try this too:

```
awk '$1>0&&$1<=22{print $1,$2,$4>"out"$1}' file
```